# Rails static page routing - is there a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, routes

To clarify, here's the situation:

I'm building a really simple CMS that will become the base for several apps I have plans to create in the future. I'd really like to be able to create a page called "About" (which will be mostly static) and automatically be able to access it at "/about", without having to modify routes.rb.

I currently have a wildcard route like this, which works just fine:

```
match '/*slug', :to => 'pages#dynamic_page', 
                :constraints => { :fullpath => /.+\.html/ }
```

The issue is, I'd really like to be able to omit the ".html" at the end. However, I prefer the extension over a url like "/pages/about". Is there a better way to handle this? The issue that occurs when I remove the constraint is that requests to items that don't exist go through the Rails router, which is obviously less than desirable, as that's extra overhead that has to be handled.

Is there a better way? Is there some way to avoid the router entirely if the page being requested is a static page, so I can eliminate the wildcard route?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this in the Rails router, tou should be able to just add a route to the very bottom of routes.rb that looks something like this:

```
match '/:slug(.:format)', :to => 'pages#dynamic_page'
```

The parentheses mark the :format parameter of the route as optional, so /about or /about.html should work.

This needs to be **at the bottom** of the routes file, so that it won't interfere with your other routes.

If you want to avoid the Rails router, you have two options, both a little more advanced.

1. In your web server's config, add a rewrite rule that maps /about to some other URI.
2. Add a Rack middleware or Rails metal to handle your static page routes. This avoids running these requests through the whole Rails routing stack, but the Rails 3 router is pretty fast and I'm not sure it's worth it to add this much complexity just to serve a semi-static page.

You may also wanna look into the [High Voltage gem](http://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage). It's a Rails engine for serving up mostly static pages. By default it gives you a /pages/about style URL, but you could then add the following to your routes to make it prettier:

```
# High Voltage treats pages like a REST resource; the page's name is the ID 
match '/:id(.:format)', :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show'
```

Comment: Thanks - the problem with having the format optional, though, is that browsers then start making requests to /favicon.ico, and those requests go through the dynamic_page method in my PagesController. The first thing that happens in said method is a hit to the database to see if there are any matching pages with a url slug of 'favicon' or 'favicon.ico' - I'd really like to avoid the hits to the database. That's why I have the .html constraint on there right now.

Comment: Do you have a static favicon.ico file? Unfortunately browsers are going to ask for one, and I prefer not to build a crazy complicated solution just to work around that, so I just put a blank favicon file in my public directory and call it done. You could even just make it an empty text file—the browser will choke on it, but it would also choke on the 500 error from your app, and this way there's no DB hit.

Comment: I don't, but I suppose I can if needed. My primary concern is just that every time a 404 or a routing error comes up, it will pass through that route unnecessarily.

Comment: That _will_ happen, but it's not such a big deal. If your dynamic page database record isn't found Rails should handle that as a 404 anyway (that's the default error code for ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound).